# Selecting all the elements which doesn`t contain particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just trying my hands on the Jquery selectors. When was operating with DOM tree, I have got a scenario where I need to select all the specific elements which doesn`t have a particular classname.

I am getting the elements which I want to make operations through JavaScript. Please find the code below.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("someID").childNodes[3].childNodes[1].children;
```

Requirement is now simple that, I don`t want remove all the elements from the elem variable which has a class .empty.

I have see .not method in JQuery, however that doesn`t seem to be helpful as I don`t know how to apply it here.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("someID").childNodes[3].childNodes[1].children;

$(elem+ ":not(.empty)");
```

Please let me know where I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**

```
$(elem).filter(":not(.empty)")
```

or **[`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not)**

```
$(elem).not('.empty')
```